# How to dynamically insert an external animated SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Inserting an animated SVG via jquery (or plain javascript) makes them appear static in Chrome and Edge, although they show up fine in Firefox:

```
$(".loader").prepend("<svg><use xlink:href='/images/icons.svg#loading-ring'></use></svg>");
```

Inserting from a separate file and using an object or img tag seems to work fine in Firefox and Chrome, but still not Edge:

```
$(".loader").prepend("<object data='/images/loading-ring.svg' type='image/svg+xml'></object>");
```

Also see:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9ghrxeq/3/)

Am I going about this the wrong way or is browser compatibility just really spotty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **you are right**, unfortunately edge and old ie doesn't support the svg animations with SMIL.

Check here: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20animation

Comment: That's too bad. Looks like Chrome has been pushing to deprecate them too. I guess I should look into css animations.